# Catch Exception in for Loop Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-catch

I have the below for loop:

```
for batch in loader:
    # do something with batch
    ...
```

My loop sometimes fails, while extracting the batch from the loader. What I want to do is something similar to snippet below, but I would like to be able to continue the loop on the next value, rather than skip the rest of the values.

```
error_idxs = [] 

try:
    for i,batch in enumerate(loader):
        # do something with batch
        ...
except:
    error_idxs.append(i)
```

The problem with the method above is that it exits out of the loop as soon as an exception happens rather than continuing with the next batch.

Is there a way to continue looping at the next batch?

Comment: just put the try/except inside the loop instead of outside the loop

Comment: If the loader fails how could you ask it again ? And so when stopping ?

Comment: When the loader fail, you can ask it again after that error ? quite strange

Comment: I am trying to capture the error in the loop part of the code. So my error occurs while extracting the batch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
error_idxs = []
i = 0
while True:
    try:
        batch = next(loader)
        # do something
    except StopIteration:
        break
    except Exception:
        error_idxs.append(i)
    finally:
        i += 1
```

Edit: Corrected `StopIterationError` to `StopIteration` and removed `continue`

Comment: I think that might just do it. May I ask what the StopIterationError is for?

Comment: Is it to exit if the iterator runs out of values? @sunnytown

Comment: Yes, [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) will raise a [`StopIteration`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) exception when the iterator is exhausted.

Comment: `StopIteration` is raised when the iterable (so the loader) runs out of new values. A `for` loop automatically catches the `StopIteration` behind the scenes and uses it to know when it should stop. The `while` loop doesn't, since it runs forever, therefore we gotta catch it ourselves.

Comment: Btw. if you know the exact exception that is raised when your loader has a connection problem, then I recommend you write that error in instead of `Exception`. If you don't do that, it will catch all possible exceptions, which is something you want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You may use while loop instead.

Here it will be extracted inside loop so exception can be caught inside loop and handled and continued with rest!

```
error_idxs = [] 

i = -1
while i < len(loader) -1:
    try:
        i = i + 1
        batch = loader[i]
        do something witth batch
        ...
    except:
        error_idxs.append(i)
```

Comment: Why calculate the length of `loader` every iteration of the loop? It's not changing in your example.